# Problem with missing() in functions I wrote

Tags: r

I have written some functions that call each other. Some arguments are optional and I am using `missing()` to control how the function works. However, when I use `lapply` or equivalent, the argument is not missing according to `missing` but is when I try to access the value.

Here is a minimal example.

```r
f <- function(x, y){
  lapply(y, function(Y) h(x = x))
}

h <- function(x){
  print(missing(x))
  if(!missing(x)){print(x)}
}  


f(y = 1:2)
#> [1] FALSE
#> Error in print(x): argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

How should I have written this?

Answer (score 2):

If the `x` argument is optional for `f`, then you use `...` in your definition of `f`.  The `...` notation allows for arguments that will be passed to other functions. These `...` arguments can be treated as optional by `f`. In your definition of `f`, you specified a required `x` argument. The error is being generated by `f` not finding `x`. R never gets to `h`.

```
f <- function(y, ...){
  lapply(y, function(Y) h(...))
}
f(y = 1:2)
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

f(y = 1:2, x = 1)
[1] FALSE
[1] 1
[1] FALSE
[1] 1
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1
```

Comment: I like this idea and hope I can get it working. My actual code may be more complex - f() calls g() if length(y) > 1. g() iterates over y, calling f() repeatedly)

Comment: I'm failing to get my function to work with this, but toy example works fine. Going to try using NULL as a default instead

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable name `x` in two places, so it's hard to talk about your code.  Here's a version that renames each of them.  I believe according to R scoping rules, this code does the same as yours:

```
f <- function(x1, y){
  lapply(y, function(Y) h(x2 = x1))
}

h <- function(x2){
  print(missing(x2))
  if(!missing(x2)){print(x2)}
}  

f(y = 1:2)
```

Now it's easier to discuss:

In your `lapply` call, you have this function:

```
function(Y) h(x2 = x1)
```

That gives an explicit expression for argument `x2`, so it is not missing.  It is the result of evaluating the expression `x1`, which is not used in the call to `f()`, so you get the error when you evaluate that expression.

Perhaps you want the function in `lapply` to be

```
function(Y) h(x2 = Y)
```

in which case `missing(x2)` would always be false (same as above), but since `Y` would take on the values in argument `y` to `f()`, the `print(x2)` would work.

Or perhaps you really did want to test for missingness of `x1` in the call to `f()`, in which case you have to do the test in `f()`:  by scoping rules, `h()` can't see `x1`, and the `missing()` function can only be called on arguments.  You could fix this by using

```
f <- function(x1, y){
  xmissing <- missing(x1)
  lapply(y, function(Y) h(x2 = x1, xmissing = xmissing))
}
h <- function(x2, xmissing){
  print(xmissing)
  if(!xmissing){print(x2)}
}
```

This `xmissing` approach can be ugly, especially if (as the comment says) there are several arguments that might be missing.  In that case a good strategy is to set a default value and test for that.  It should be one that the user wouldn't normally use.  That depends on context, but `NULL` is a common choice.  For example,

```
f <- function(x1 = NULL, y){
  lapply(y, function(Y) h(x2 = x1))
}
h <- function(x2){
  print(is.null(x2))
  if(!is.null(x2)) {print(x2)}
}
```

Comment: `xmissing` could work, but I have many optional arguments, ....

Comment: You can set defaults to `NULL` or some other impossible value, and then test for that.  Unlike missingness, `NULL` will be passed along.  I'll modify my answer.